# A characterization of finite purely inseparable extensions of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $K/k$ be a finite extension of fields. Let $A=K \otimes_k K$.

An exercise:
Show that $K/k$ is purely inseparable $\Leftrightarrow A/J(A) \cong k$, where $J(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$.

It doesn't seem right to me. I can show that $A/J(A)$ is a product of copies of fields, each containing $K$. So that must mean that $A/J(A) \cong k$ implies $k=K$, making the $\Leftarrow$ direction trivial and $\Rightarrow$ direction wrong.

Am I correct?

Maybe $A/J(A) \cong K$ instead of $A/A(J) \cong k$ would make it correct?

Comment: Where did you get that exercise whose statement is false and which is quite difficult when corrected? Students  are sometimes handled roughly here by users who criticize the way they ask questions. Fair enough, but I think that teachers' questions should not  be  above criticism either...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalence in the exercise is indeed  false: since  $A$ is a $K$-algebra (multiply elements of $K\otimes_k K$ by elements of $K$ through the left factor, say) , so is  $A/J(A)$ which can thus never equal $k$ if the extension 
$k\subset K$ is not trivial.
You are also right that for *any* finite-dimensional extension  $k\to K$,  purely inseparable or not, $A/J(A)$ is  isomorphic to the  product $\Pi F_i$ of a finite number (maybe equal to one!) of field extensions $K\to F_i$ (this follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem).
Notice also that   since $A$ is finite-dimensional over $K$, it is an artinian ring, so that the Jacobson radical coincides with the nilpotent radical : $J(A)=Nil(A)$.

The correct implication is  (as you suggested) :    $$\quad K/k  \:\;\text {is purely inseparable} \Leftrightarrow A/Nil(A) =K$$

**Edit**
Since I  find  this equivalence rather difficult, I'll upgrade my preceding indications  to a concise proof.

$\boxed {\Longleftarrow}$
 Notice first that the hypothesis forces $A=K\oplus Nil(A)$.
Consider the separable part of your extension: $k\subset K_{sep }\subset K$.
 Since $K\otimes _k K_{sep }\subset K\otimes _k K$ is reduced (separable extensions are universally reduced!) , we must have $ K\otimes _k K_{sep }=K \subset K\oplus Nil(A)$ and thus $K_{sep }=k$, so that  $k\subset K$ is indeed purely inseparable.

$\boxed {\Longrightarrow}$
It suffices to  show that every element of $ K\otimes_k K\setminus K\otimes_k k$ 
 is nilpotent.
And for that it suffices to show that  for any  $b\in K$ the set  $ K\otimes_k k(b) \setminus K\otimes_k k$ is composed of nilpotents of $K\otimes_k k(b) $.
But $k(b) \simeq k[T]/(T^{p^r}-q) \;\; (q\in k, q=b^{p^r})$ by pure inseparability and so $K\otimes_k k(b) \simeq K[T]/(T^{p^r}-q) =K[T]/(T-b)^{p^r}$
In that  last isomorphism the set $ K\otimes_k k(b) \setminus K\otimes_k k$ corresponds to the set $K[T]/(T-b)^{p^r} \setminus K$, and this last set is indeed composed of nilpotents. More precisely, it is the nilpotent radical $(\bar T-b)$ of 
$K[T]/(T-b)^{p^r}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for both parts of the answer! By the way, I meant that $A/J(A)$ is a product of a finite number of fields, not necessarily a product of 2 fields. This is true irregardless of whether $K/k$ is purely inseparable or not. In the purely inseparable case I assume that this finite number turns out to be 1 (this is just to help a future reader of this question and answer).

Comment: Dear @Amy: if you allow products of just one factor, what you say is indeed completely correct . I'll edit my answer in order to suppress my unfair remark, for which I apologize.

Comment: I have also edited  my answer into a concise proof of the correct equivalence,  since I feel that my preceding "hints" were  a bit too cryptic .

Comment: Dear Georges: For the implication $\boxed\implies$, I wonder if the following is correct. There is a unique $k$-embedding of $K$ into a fixed algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $K$, and thus (by universal property of $K\otimes_kK$) a unique $K$-morphism from $K\otimes_kK$ into $\Omega$, and thus a unique maximal ideal in $K\otimes_kK$.

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves, what you say is indeed correct, but I don't see why  $K\otimes_k K$ modulo your maximal ideal could not be a strict  extension of $K$ rather than $K$.

Comment: Dear Georges: Thanks! My (perhaps incorrect) argument goes as follows. Let $f$ be a $k$-algebra morphism from $K\otimes_kK$ to $\Omega$. Then there are $k$-algebra morphisms $g$ and $h$ from $K$ to $\Omega$ such that $f(x\otimes y)=g(x)h(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $K$. But, $K/k$ being purely inseparable, we have $g(x)=x$ and $h(y)=y$, implying that the image of $f$ is $K$.

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves, your argument is not only correct, but also very  crisp and elegant: congratulations!(Oserais-je une question personnelle: est-ce que vous vous levez très tôt pour travailler ou êtes-vous à l'étranger?)

Comment: Dear Georges. Thanks for the kind words. (Non, je suis en France. Je suis plutôt matinal, mais j'ai des horaires de veille et de sommeil très irréguliers. --- Entre collègues, ne pourrions-nous pas nous tutoyer?)

Comment: @Pierre-Yves:excellente  idée, et rappelle-moi à l'ordre si j'oublie!

Comment: Tu peux compter sur moi! Une question personnelle à mon tour: Te souviens-tu de mon collègue François Chargois?

Comment: Cher @Pierre-Yves, oui but let us continue this conversation privately, so as not to bore our friends here: `myname`@unice.fr